# How used function drupal_render_children in file twig?

Tags: theming, 8

I want use function `drupal_render_children` in file *.html.twig Drupal 8. What solution for do ?

Comment: You don't need to do this. It should be built in to print `{{ children }}` in a twig template if that render array has children or whatever key of the render array has children.

Comment: sure ! variable `{{ children }}` working ! Thanks for your share !

Comment: Which variables should be affected to children ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one, [it is deprecated](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render_children/8.2.x). Two, you cannot use PHP functions directly within the Twig template.

You can implement the appropriate preprocess hook to do this, to pass to Twig as a variable.